# What's the correct way to use pair completion?

Tags: autocompletion

I've disabled pair completion because it doesn't really save any key presses. I have to press right arrow to get out of a quote after completing the string. Am I missing something here?

For example:

If I have to enter `func("hello")`, after some typing I will get `func("hello|")` with cursor at |, and I will have to press at least two more keys(esc-o/A) to get out of declaration and continue editing, which could very well be used to enters `"` and a `)`.

Comment: I personally didn't understand the question. If you disabled the completion, why do you need to press the arrow key to move over the quote? The quote should not be there, if I'm getting you correctly. The second point why do you use the arrow, instead of the `l` key to move one char to the right?

Comment: @user907860 Aren't they saying that they disabled completion because they had to press  the arrow key?

Comment: @Alex, yes, it might be. Then the question must have been this: *What is the easiest way to skip over the chars inserted by the pair completion*

Comment: Sorry for late reply, added an example.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a plugin such as [delimitMate](https://github.com/Raimondi/delimitMate) or [auto-pairs](https://github.com/jiangmiao/auto-pairs), they have options that allow you to skip over the closed pair by pressing the closing key.  If you press `[`, then you press `]`.  `(` then `)`. `"` then `"`, etc.

Yes, you're still typing the closing character.  The point of using these plugins is that the closing character will be in the *right place* when you're done editing.  They also remove the closing pair if you press `<bs>` to delete the opening pair.  Whether or not these features are advantages is up to you.

IMO, typing speed isn't always improved with less keystrokes.  There's times where it's improved by predictable reactions to keystrokes.  These plugins allow you to forego the need to balance delimiters yourself in most cases.

Comment: I've never liked auto pairing in any editor for this reason. It usually gets in the way more than it helps.

Comment: @Tumbler41 To each their own.  This feature does more good than harm for me since I almost always go back to normal mode and use motions after closing braces.  For arguments, I have a habit of using `<esc>A, ` so I can undo arguments individually.  It's kinda nice that the closing paren/brace stays when pressing `u`.

Answer (score 0):

As it has been pointed out, this feature doesn't really save any keystrokes, however it helps keeping these pairs balanced.

Note however that [lh-brackets](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-brackets/) has two ways to close all current bracket pairs. The first is bound to the semi colon in C and C++. The second is bound to an tunable keybindind. This is (one of the?) the only case where keystrokes can be saved. I can't tell whether the more popular alternative have (yet?) implemented this feature.